# KeyError: 'active_id' openerp

Tags: openerp-7

I've changed record rules for project purpose after that when I click on "My Current Time sheet throwing below error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204,      in dispatch
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118- 002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1432, in run
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send

Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line  89, in send
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in  dispatch_rpc
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 132, in   wrapper
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 199, in execute
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  File "F:\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-     002423\Server\server\openerp\addons\smsclient\serveraction.py", line 47, in run
  KeyError: 'active_id'

Answer (score 0):

Once if you give record rule with domain_force condition, it will store in your db (ir.rule) . Even comment/remove that code, it will work.
You've to make that condition as empty []. Then upgrade the respective module. it will work..

Example:

[('employee_id.user_id', '=', user.id)]

---

if you want to remove the domain_force give like this:

[]

Then upgrade, and comment/remove that respective line